# Where and how can I install ArcPy for Python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, gis, arcpy

I have checked http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/, http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003m00000002000000.htm, and https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygeoif/0.4.1

None of these logical places can I download arcpy for installation. I have also tried Pip install arcpy. Nothing works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ArcPy is part of ArcGIS, which is not free software. You need to obtain a license for ArcGIS to use ArcPy.

If that's not an option, consider open source options, such as GDAL and many others.

Comment: I see, what is the best learning material (website tutorial or textbook) I can learn about it? I found such teaching material are scarce and usually touching on very superficial level.

Comment: It depends what you need to do, there's actually lots out there (websites, books). For Q&A, [GIS.SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com/) is a good resource.