# Could not find a version

Tags: python, operating-system, pip

I'm on mac trying to install the module "arcpy" with pip. I use this command:

```
pip install --user arcpy
```

And I get this error:

```
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement os (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for arcpy
```

Can someone tell me the problem?

Comment: You don't need to install `os`, It is already installed.

Comment: @Megalng ok but it happend to me with the module "arcpy" too.

Comment: You cannot install arcpy with pip.. it's not a free software. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31328368/where-and-how-can-i-install-arcpy-for-python-2-7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where and how can I install ArcPy for Python 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31328368/where-and-how-can-i-install-arcpy-for-python-2-7)

Answer (score 1):

Update:
Original question was asking about `os` package and then it was replaced with `arcpy`. To summarize:

- `os` module is already part of the Python core library. You can just import it in your Python code. External `os` package does not exist in Python package index.
- `arcpy` is not a free software and cannot be installed with pip

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. Where is there a mention of the `os` module anywhere?

Comment: The original question was edited. Originally it was asking about `os` package, with no mention of `arcpy`.

Comment: Well, might as well delete.

Comment: Also ArcPy only runs on Windows.